# Pre Processing Data for Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, apache-beam, tensorflow-transform

When I run my tensorflow model I am receiving this error `InvalidArgumentError: Field 4 in record 0 is not a valid float: latency
     [[Node: DecodeCSV = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING], field_delim=",", na_value="", use_quote_delim=true](arg0, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_1, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_2, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_3, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_4, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_5, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_6, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_7, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_8, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_9, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_10, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_11, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_12, DecodeCSV/record_defaults_13)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?]], output_types=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]`

I believe this issue is in the preprocessing step that creates the csv files that my model reads data from as it believes it should receive the first `Node` pattern but instead gets the second `Node` pattern.

This is my preprocessing code (I purposely cast the dtypes from the query to ensure they would be read correctly):

```
query = """
SELECT CAST(end_time AS STRING) AS end_time, CAST(device AS STRING) AS device, CAST(device_os AS STRING) AS device_os, CAST(device_os_version AS STRING) AS device_os_version, CAST(latency AS FLOAT) AS latency,
CAST(megacycles AS FLOAT) AS megacycles, CAST(cost AS FLOAT) AS cost, CAST(status AS STRING) AS Status, CAST(device_brand AS STRING) AS device_brand, CAST(device_family AS STRING) AS device_family,
CAST(browser_version AS STRING) AS browser_version, CAST(app AS STRING) AS app, CAST(ua_parse AS STRING) AS ua_parse
FROM [<mytable>:daily_logs.app_logs_data]
WHERE start_time >='2018-04-16'
GROUP BY end_time, device, device_os, device_os_version, latency, megacycles, cost, Status, device_brand, device_family, browser_version, app, ua_parse
"""
def preprocess_tft(inputs):
    import copy
    import numpy as np
    def center(x):
          return x - tft.mean(x)
    result = copy.copy(inputs) # shallow copy
    result['end_time'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['end_time'])
    result['device'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['device'])
    result['device_os'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['device_os'])
    result['device_os_version'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['device_os_version'])
    result['latency_tft'] = center(inputs['latency'])
    result['megacycles_tft'] = center(inputs['megacycles'])
    result['cost_tft'] = center(inputs['cost'])
    result['Status'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['Status'])
    result['device_brand'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['device_brand'])
    result['device_family'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['device_family'])
    result['browser_version'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['browser_version'])
    result['app'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['app'])
    result['ua_parse'] = tft.string_to_int(inputs['ua_parse'])
    return result
    #return inputs

def cleanup(rowdict):
    import copy, hashlib
    CSV_COLUMNS ='end_time,device,device_os,device_os_version,latency,megacycles,cost,Status,device_brand,device_family,browser_version,app,ua_parse'.split(',')
    STR_COLUMNS = 'key,end_time,device,device_os,device_os_version,Status,device_brand,device_family,browser_version,app,ua_parse'.split(',')
    FLT_COLUMNS = 'latency,megacycles,cost'.split(',')

    # add any missing columns, and correct the types
    def tofloat(value, ifnot):
      try:
        return float(value)
      except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return ifnot

    result = {
      k : str(rowdict[k]) if k in rowdict else 'None' for k in STR_COLUMNS
    }
    result.update({
        k : tofloat(rowdict[k], -99) if k in rowdict else -99 for k in FLT_COLUMNS
      })    

    # cleanup: write out only the data we that we want to train on
    if result['latency'] > 0 and result['megacycles'] > 0 and result['cost'] > 0:
      data = ','.join([str(result[k]) for k in CSV_COLUMNS])
      result['key'] = hashlib.sha224(data).hexdigest()
      yield result

def preprocess(query, in_test_mode):
  import os
  import os.path
  import tempfile
  import tensorflow as tf
  from apache_beam.io import tfrecordio
  from tensorflow_transform.coders import example_proto_coder
  from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_metadata
  from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import dataset_schema
  from tensorflow_transform.beam.tft_beam_io import transform_fn_io

  job_name = 'preprocess-log-features' + '-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S')    
  if in_test_mode:
    import shutil
    print 'Launching local job ... hang on'
    OUTPUT_DIR = './preproc_tft'
    shutil.rmtree(OUTPUT_DIR, ignore_errors=True)
  else:
    print 'Launching Dataflow job {} ... hang on'.format(job_name)
    OUTPUT_DIR = 'gs://{0}/logs2/preproc_tft/'.format(BUCKET)
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call('gsutil rm -r {}'.format(OUTPUT_DIR).split())

  options = {
    'staging_location': os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'tmp', 'staging'),
    'temp_location': os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'tmp'),
    'job_name': job_name,
    'project': PROJECT,
    'max_num_workers': 24,
    'teardown_policy': 'TEARDOWN_ALWAYS',
    'no_save_main_session': True,
    'requirements_file': 'requirements.txt'
  }
  opts = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
  if in_test_mode:
    RUNNER = 'DirectRunner'
  else:
    RUNNER = 'DataflowRunner'

  # set up metadata  
  raw_data_schema = {
    colname : dataset_schema.ColumnSchema(tf.string, [], dataset_schema.FixedColumnRepresentation())
                   for colname in 'key,end_time,device,device_os,device_os_version,Status,device_brand,device_family,browser_version,app,ua_parse'.split(',')
  }
  raw_data_schema.update({
      colname : dataset_schema.ColumnSchema(tf.float32, [], dataset_schema.FixedColumnRepresentation())
                for colname in 'latency,megacycles,cost'.split(',')
    })
  raw_data_metadata = dataset_metadata.DatasetMetadata(dataset_schema.Schema(raw_data_schema))

  def read_rawdata(p, step, test_mode):
    if step == 'train':
        selquery = 'SELECT * FROM ({})'.format(query)
    else:
      selquery = 'SELECT * FROM ({})'.format(query)
    if in_test_mode:
        selquery = selquery + ' LIMIT 100'
    #print 'Processing {} data from {}'.format(step, selquery)
    return (p 
          | '{}_read'.format(step) >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=selquery, use_standard_sql=False))
          | '{}_cleanup'.format(step) >> beam.FlatMap(cleanup)
                   )

  # run Beam  
  with beam.Pipeline(RUNNER, options=opts) as p:
    with beam_impl.Context(temp_dir=os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'tmp')):

      # analyze and transform training       
      raw_data = read_rawdata(p, 'train', in_test_mode)
      raw_dataset = (raw_data, raw_data_metadata)
      transformed_dataset, transform_fn = (
          raw_dataset | beam_impl.AnalyzeAndTransformDataset(preprocess_tft))
      transformed_data, transformed_metadata = transformed_dataset
      _ = transformed_data | 'WriteTrainData' >> tfrecordio.WriteToTFRecord(
          os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'train'),
          coder=example_proto_coder.ExampleProtoCoder(
              transformed_metadata.schema))

      # transform eval data
      raw_test_data = read_rawdata(p, 'eval', in_test_mode)
      raw_test_dataset = (raw_test_data, raw_data_metadata)
      transformed_test_dataset = (
          (raw_test_dataset, transform_fn) | beam_impl.TransformDataset())
      transformed_test_data, _ = transformed_test_dataset
      _ = transformed_test_data | 'WriteTestData' >> tfrecordio.WriteToTFRecord(
          os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'eval'),
          coder=example_proto_coder.ExampleProtoCoder(
              transformed_metadata.schema))
      _ = (transform_fn
           | 'WriteTransformFn' >>
           transform_fn_io.WriteTransformFn(os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'metadata')))

  job = p.run()
  if in_test_mode:
    job.wait_until_finish()
    print "Done!"

preprocess(query, in_test_mode=False)
```

Is there a way to print out the dtypes before I send it into the Beam pipeline so I can check the dtypes array and make sure it is valid? Is there something in the code that is causing the dtypes to be different or arranged in a different order then specified in the `CSV_COLUMNS`variable?

Comment: I have a question regarding selquery = 'SELECT * FROM ({})'.format(query), why can't you use query directly? Another thing if you want to print the data after reading from big table you can add another beam.Map that simply prints and returns the original record.

Comment: @Elmer Full disclosure, I followed a code sample to build this preprocess so I am speculating on the purpose. Given the arguments for beam (which I am still learning) and that there is an `if` for test mode, this cleans up the code. I was looking to understand the data types was complete as it appears to be changing my data types as my tensorflow model (reference the error) seems to be getting a different array of data types.

Comment: I would suggest the following since there's no difference between the train and eval query just do selquery = query and remove the if statement.

Comment: @Elmer Thanks. Still running into the same issue. Do you know how I would print my data types after the clean function executes?

Comment: def echo(record): print('>>', record) return record With the appropriate line breaks, then on read_rawdata do: | '{}_print'.format(step) >> beam.Map(echo)